# Refactoring bash command into tcsh command

Tags: bash, tcsh, environment-modules

I have problem with refactoring bash command into tcsh-friendly command. Don't know the tcsh syntax very well so the error im receiving doens't give me any clue.

The whole bash script was about adding modules on server

```
MODULEPATH=/app/modules/0/modulefiles:/env/common/modules
export MODULEPATH
module() { eval `/app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd sh "$@"` ;}
```

I changed first two commands to tcsh already

```
setenv MODULEPATH /app/modules/0/modulefiles:/env/common/modules
set MODULEPATH
```

But i dont know how to change the syntax of last command. Console is returning me error "Badly placed ()'s.".

Can I ask for little lesson what to change in this command to be tcsh-friendly?

Comment: tcsh doesn't have functions at all. From what I recall, you'd have to write an alias instead. I question whether this is worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

chepner is right saying *tcsh doesn't have functions at all* and *you'd have to write an alias instead.* That's not much of an effort for your one-line function:

```
alias module 'eval `/app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd sh \!*`'
```

Basically, we prepend `alias`, remove `()` and `{}`, quote and replace `"$@"` with `\!*`.

Answer (score 0):

The `module` command you want to port from bash to tcsh already comes with an initialization file to the tcsh shell. For all shells or scripting languages `module` is compatible with, there is an initialization file provided in the `init` directory of the software.

So from your example, Modules is installed in `/app/modules/0`, so you should have a `/app/modules/0/init` directory and a `/app/modules/0/init/tcsh` script to initialize the module command for tcsh. You just have to source it to initialize the `module` command:

```
source /app/modules/0/init/tcsh
```

As Armali says, the module command on tcsh is defined with the `alias` shell command.

With recent version of Modules (version 4+), you also have the possibility to define the `module` command in your current shell session with the `autoinit` subcommand of the `modulecmd` script:

```
eval `/app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd tcsh autoinit`
```